# Upgrading from VS2019 community to professional version got errro CS0579

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have upgraded VS2019 community version to the professional version and I have developed a dynamic web site. now when I build the solution I get the following error:

CS0579 Duplicate 'global::system.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute'

plz guide as I am new to VS2019

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to each of the *.csproj files:

```
<GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
```

Comment: ok i found it and when i put it at the end before </Project> it says the said element is unrecognized

Answer (score 0):

exclude folder "obj" from solution solve my problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35401938)